# MongoDB return Error with code 13 and description Unauthorized

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, cloud

I use NodeChef Cloud platform to upload my NodeJS project with MongoDB database

I connect to DB with connection string in this format:

`mongodb://user:pass@host:port/database_name`

After deploy I try to get data from DB, but Mongo return error like this:

```
{
    "operationTime": "6962418569824960513",
    "ok": 0,
    "code": 13,
    "codeName": "Unauthorized",
    ...
    "name": "MongoError"
}
```

MongoDB version is **4.0.3**

To connect to DB in project I use NodeJS lib `mongod` and code like this:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URI, (err, database) => {

});
```

Comment: What is not clear with this error message? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63755470/3027266

Comment: I use full connection string with login and password. I don't understand, why I as authorized user can't make requests to DB

Comment: Did you read the linked answer? Unless you provide the non working command it is difficult to give any help.